# How to change location of the small pictures regarding the big one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can create the gallery using existing code:

[How to create gallery from the existing one on Java Script using mouse over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871724/how-to-create-gallery-from-the-existing-one-on-java-script-using-mouse-over/45949671#45949671)

Right now all my small pictures on the right of the big one.

What needs to change to place some of the pictures on the left and some on the right and some of the bottom of the big picture?

Also, I’ve got rid of some redundancies in the code but I still wondering if I could do something else and DRY by deleting some code (see below).

Thanks.

Code as below.
(Could I delete some part of the code at the very bottom?)

```js
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d = document;
  if (d.images) {
    if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
    var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
      a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
        d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
        d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
      }
  }
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i, x, a = document.MM_sr;
  for (i = 0; a && i < a.length && (x = a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) x.src = x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p, i, x;
  if (!d) d = document;
  if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
    d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
    n = n.substring(0, p);
  }
  if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
  for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++) x = d.forms[i][n];
  for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++) x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
  if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
  return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i, j = 0,
    x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments;
  document.MM_sr = new Array;
  for (i = 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
    if ((x = MM_findObj(a[i])) != null) {
      document.MM_sr[j++] = x;
      if (!x.oSrc) x.oSrc = x.src;
      x.src = a[i + 2];
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>children</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFb0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('1-b.jpg','2-b.jpg','3-b.jpg','4-b.jpg','5-b.jpg','6-b.jpg','7-b','8-b','9-b')">
  <center>
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (children.psd) -->
    <table id="Table_01" border="0" width="851" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; font-size: 18pt;">Some title</span></p>
            <p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="72" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="7" rowspan="9"><img id="biggest_one" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="photo_over/4.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="640" name="biggest_one" /></td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="18"></td>
          <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="8" rowspan="9">
            <p><img src="photo_over/1a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','1-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/2a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','2-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/3a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','3-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/4a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','4-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/5a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','5-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/6a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','6-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
              <img src="photo_over/7a.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','7-b.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="82" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="61" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="58" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="87" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="109" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="54" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="59" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
  </center>
</body>

</html>



//can this part of code be deleted?

</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="87" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="109" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="54" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="59" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></td>
</tr>
```

//EDITED

Code below shows the same output as on example in FireFox but on Safari the bottom picture and title is not in the center. 
I think there is a problem how output display on Safari  10.1

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297018/safari-10-1-doesn-t-display-the-page-correctly/297019?noredirect=1#comment375203_297019

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Children</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d = document;
  if (d.images) {
    if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
    var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
      a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
        d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
        d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
      }
  }
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i, x, a = document.MM_sr;
  for (i = 0; a && i < a.length && (x = a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) x.src = x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p, i, x;
  if (!d) d = document;
  if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
    d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
    n = n.substring(0, p);
  }
  if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
  for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++) x = d.forms[i][n];
  for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++) x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
  if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
  return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i, j = 0,
    x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments;
  document.MM_sr = new Array;
  for (i = 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
    if ((x = MM_findObj(a[i])) != null) {
      document.MM_sr[j++] = x;
      if (!x.oSrc) x.oSrc = x.src;
      x.src = a[i + 2];
    }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .pics-wrapper {
  display: flex; justify-content:center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-pics p,
.right-pics p 

{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFb0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('1-b.jpg','2-b.jpg','3-b.jpg','4-b.jpg','5-b.jpg','6-b.jpg','7-b','8-b','9-b')">
  <center>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1> Some title </h1>
      <div class="pics-wrapper">
        <div class="left-pics">
          <p>
            <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"
            />
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg/150px-Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg/150px-Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <table id="Table_01" border="0" width="851" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="9"><img id="biggest_one" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="640" name="biggest_one"
              /></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="3" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="right-pics">
          <p>
            <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103678916/image.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media.timeout.com/images/103678916/image.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-pic">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/simpleview/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_510,q_75,w_1280/v1/clients/newyorkstate/dumbo_brooklyn_bridge_park_julienne_schaer_0732_fdff1de5-9486-480c-a1c7-4135d784c75f.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://res.cloudinary.com/simpleview/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_510,q_75,w_1280/v1/clients/newyorkstate/dumbo_brooklyn_bridge_park_julienne_schaer_0732_fdff1de5-9486-480c-a1c7-4135d784c75f.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

// EDITED 2

```
.left-pics p,
.right-pics p {            
  display: -ms-flexbox;      
  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
   margin: -2px;
}
```

//EDIT3

```
.left-pics img,
.right-pics img 
.bottom-pic img
{
  padding:2px;
}

.bottom-pic img
{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to eliminate as much as I can from the code you provided and I found that to help you, I had to edit the structure of your current html. Your code was really messy and you used a table when you don't have to use one. You can see the structure and an example below. Hope it helps!

I saw that you had a lot of empty .gif files. However I couldn't figure the point of them, so I had to remove them to clean up the code and make the code work properly

**EDIT**

If you want to change the way the small pictures are aligned, you can do it using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

See the following code:

```
@media (max-width:960px) {
 .left-pics p,
 .right-pics p 
 {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

Once the browser reaches 960px resolution or lower, the `flex-direction` of `.right-pic` and `.left-pic` will change from `flex-direction:row` to `flex-direction:column`. You can use this to align the 3 small pictures how you want, once the browser reaches a certain resolution.

**EDIT 2** :

To add spaces between the images, just add a `padding:2px;` at the `img` tag.

```
.left-pics img,
.right-pics img {
  padding:2px;
}
```

**Example below:** ( test it on full page and resize your browser )

```js
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d = document;
  if (d.images) {
    if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
    var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
      a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
        d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
        d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
      }
  }
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i, x, a = document.MM_sr;
  for (i = 0; a && i < a.length && (x = a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) x.src = x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p, i, x;
  if (!d) d = document;
  if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
    d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
    n = n.substring(0, p);
  }
  if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
  for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++) x = d.forms[i][n];
  for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++) x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
  if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
  return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i, j = 0,
    x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments;
  document.MM_sr = new Array;
  for (i = 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
    if ((x = MM_findObj(a[i])) != null) {
      document.MM_sr[j++] = x;
      if (!x.oSrc) x.oSrc = x.src;
      x.src = a[i + 2];
    }
}
//-->
```

```css
    .pics-wrapper {           
  display: -ms-flexbox;      
  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex; 
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

table {             
  display: -ms-flexbox;      
  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-pics p,
.right-pics p {            
  display: -ms-flexbox;      
  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-pics img,
.right-pics img {
  padding:2px;
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
 .left-pics p,
 .right-pics p 
 {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
   }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>children</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFb0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('1-b.jpg','2-b.jpg','3-b.jpg','4-b.jpg','5-b.jpg','6-b.jpg','7-b','8-b','9-b')">
  <center>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1> Some title </h1>
      <div class="pics-wrapper">
        <div class="left-pics">
          <p>
            <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"
            />
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg/150px-Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg/150px-Empire_State_Building_%28HDR%29.jpg',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <table id="Table_01" border="0" width="851" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="9"><img id="biggest_one" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="640" name="biggest_one"
              /></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="3" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="right-pics">
          <p>
            <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103678916/image.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media.timeout.com/images/103678916/image.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',1)"
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
            <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-pic">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/simpleview/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_510,q_75,w_1280/v1/clients/newyorkstate/dumbo_brooklyn_bridge_park_julienne_schaer_0732_fdff1de5-9486-480c-a1c7-4135d784c75f.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','https://res.cloudinary.com/simpleview/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_510,q_75,w_1280/v1/clients/newyorkstate/dumbo_brooklyn_bridge_park_julienne_schaer_0732_fdff1de5-9486-480c-a1c7-4135d784c75f.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can your sides menu be changed programmatically that  smaller pictures  were alight  on the left, right and center and not only one under another in vertical line as it right now?

Comment: I've tried to use your code but got errors (see the code in my post after "EDITED"). Should i create separate file for css/ do something else to fix error and got the right output? thanks.

Comment: I edited the code to give it more support for older browser versions. The error you find with Safari is because you probably tested it on Safari 5.1 or Safari 6.1 which only supports the old [flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/). It will work on the newer versions.

Comment: I've checked my Safari version: it is 10.1.1.  Actually I have no error as such but output in Safari is not as supposed to be: title and bottom  small picture is not on the center. But in Fire Fox all is fine. Why is so?

Comment: I could not find the option to attach screen shot to show the difference in Safari and FireFox. Is this option exist?

Comment: Edit your orginal post and press ctrl+g

Comment: Do you refer  "Edit your orginal post and press ctrl+g" how to post screen shot or anything else? I thought that you add some code that establish the different  small picture locations, is it correct?

Comment: You wanted to attach a picture to show the difference between Safari and Firefox. You can do that if you edit your original post and press ctrl+g

Comment: I did it already: drop pictures referring 2 browser but could not see them... Should I click on some button line "safe" to be efficient?

Comment: CTRL+G -> Drag/drop picture or click to add picture -> Add Picture -> Save Edits. Should work

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you see on Safari, though. The code works well for me, there are no issues with the title and the bottom picture. DId you test again with the updated code?

Comment: I tested with code that I provided after "EDITED" Is it correct code or need to change something or there is another code that you refer as "updated"?

Comment: I edited my code around 1 hour ago, please test it again with my updated code.

Comment: link as below work in FireFox, Chrome but wrong not centered output in Safari 10.1
http://sfreorealty.com/home/studentt.html

Comment: The link as above is not updated. I'll update and let you know the result.

Comment: I've seen your last snipped (didn't code yet). Is it possible to add some space between small pictures, for ex. 2 px  vertically and  2 px horizontally(how to code it)?

Comment: Yes, just add a `padding:2px;` to the `img` element.

Comment: I've added (see after EDITED2) but it doesn't show space between small pictures. What code/where to use to see the space 2 px between the smaller ones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153418/discussion-between-user-and-ovidiu-unguru).

Comment: I've changed the location of the small pictures:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008541/how-to-change-locations-of-the-small-pictures-regarding-each-others-and-the-big/46025691#46025691

Please, let me know if something could be done differently.
thanks.